# How can I make an organized library with colors for HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, xml

For larger web projects, I find it impractical changing all the different colors, that are meant to be the same, manually.

That's why I'm wondering if it's possible to make a color library of some sort in an ordinary web project?

To give you an example, this is something that is possible in for example android studio where you'll easily be able to give colors a name in an xml-file that is normally called "color.xml":

[image: Example of how "color.xml" is built up in Android Studio by default.]

[image: Example of "color.xml" being used to set a color.]

To summarize this question:

Is this possible to achieve in a web project with for example HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS provides us with the concept of [variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables), but it's not fully supported yet so I will not run and use it in production.

This will work in chrome/firefox, but I'm not sure regarding other browsers:

```css
html {
  --main-color: #FF0000;
  --sub-color: #00FF00;
}
.main {
  color: var(--main-color);
}
.sub {
  color: var(--sub-color);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">asd</div>
<div class="sub">def</div>
```

You can also use SASS/SCSS/LESS/Stylus or many others.

Comment: This seems to work very well. I would like to note that this also worked when storing the color variables in a separate css file.

Comment: It does, but still - it's experimental (so I wouldn't count on this to work in all browsers and in future versions of the current browsers it works on).

Comment: Or LESS, or Stylus, or ...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, added them to the answer, however note that if css-variables will get into the standard we wont need any post-processing of the css we write. The browser will do this for us.

Comment: Take a look at this:
https://htmlmag.com/article/an-introduction-to-css-preprocessors-sass-less-stylus